# How to change the background color of a date cell from fullcalendar.io using angular?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, gradient

I am trying to fill specific dates with a gradient background represented by a variable.

e.g.

```js
var x = 10; // background should be fully covered by the gradient
```

---

```js
var x = 1; // background should cover only one tenth of the cell
```

Comment: Can you share us what have u tried so far? i mean code you wrote

Comment: I have looked at the documentation and haven't found any methods to do it.

Comment: This is something you can do by setting a CSS rule on the relevant element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients for an intro

Comment: I don't understand how your answer solves my question at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by adding this to the styles.scss file.

```css
td.fc-day {
  border: $border;
  position: relative;
}

td.fc-day:after {
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: $gradient;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '\A';
}
```